# How to instantly call action in Form1 on closing Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

So basically i have `Form1`

From Form1 I can open `Form2` with this code:

```
    private void btn_Komplexity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 kompleksaForma = new Form2();
        kompleksaForma.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When Form2 is opened there is something and at the end there is     `this.Close();`

After `this.Close();` (closing Form2) is it possible to call instant action on Form1?

Comment: Sure. If you have a reference to Form1 in Form2, then simply call a public method of Form1 in the Closing event of Form2. Or, if it's modal, then you can simply place code after the modal Form2 show() code in Form1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sticking to ShowDialog(), this function will block until the form is closed.

```
private void btn_Komplexity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (Form2 kompleksaForma = new Form2())
     {
         kompleksaForma.ShowDialog();
         PutStuffHereAfterClose();  // (or outside the using block if it doesn't need
                                    //  to access properties of kompleksaForma)
     }
}
```

Comment: It MIGHT not work if `PutStuffHereAfterClose` should only run in certain cases based on conditions available in `Form2`. In that case, a different approach MIGHT be better. But otherwise - yes, this is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: @Shaamaan it will work. If OP had other requirments he would've put them in the question. In this scope you have access to Form2, so there shouldnt be problems with conditionals as long as they're based on properties/functions of Form2

Comment: If you are going to call `ShowDialog`, you become responsible for calling `Dispose` on the Form object. The best way to ensure that happens is to wrap the creation in a `using` block. This is a common mistake. I've fixed the answer here so that it represents best practice.

Comment: @CodyGray sounds interesting. I always thought the Framework would handle it properly since the object goes out of scope and would be disposed when needed. Do you have any good source material about this issue?

Comment: Under no circumstances can you rely on the framework (by which you presumably mean the garbage collector running a finalizer) automatically disposing of an object that implements `IDisposable` and therefore has a `Dispose` method. If the object implements `IDisposable`, you *must* call its `Dispose` method when you are finished with it. The standard pattern for doing so is a `using` statement because this ensures that `Dispose` is called even if an exception is thrown by the intervening code. There are many reasons why a finalizer won't work. Chief among them is that finalizers are run...

Comment: non-deterministically, whereas objects with unmanaged resources must have those resources released deterministically, and that requires an explicit disposal. Another problem is that if any finalizer throws, the GC will abandon calling all remaining finalizers, leading to a memory leak. So even if you get lucky and are able to free the resources later, things may still go boom. As for "good source material", the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) is a good place to look, see the "Remarks" section.

Answer (score 0):

There are some events triggered after the window is closed. You can subscribe to them and add your code to the handler method:

```
Form2 kompleksaForma = new Form2();

kompleksaForma.FormClosing += KompleksaForma_FormClosing;
kompleksaForma.FormClosed += KompleksaForma_FormClosed;
kompleksaForma.Deactivate += KompleksaForma_Deactivate;

kompleksaForma.ShowDialog();
```

And then implement one of the handlers like that:

```
private void KompleksaForma_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code here
}

private void KompleksaForma_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // or here
}

private void KompleksaForma_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // or here
}
```

First will trigger `FormClosing`, then `FormClosed`. Last one is `Deactivate`.

Comment: The precise order in which these events are raised during a form's closure should be considered an implementation detail and not relied upon. Select the one that makes the most *logical* sense for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're showing Form2 as a modal window using `form2.ShowDialog()` or `form2.ShowDialog(this)`, then...

```
form2.ShowDialog(this);
if (form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    CallOtherStuffHere();
}
```

... as the ShowDialog() method will block execution until the closure of Form2, then continue.

I'm using DialogResult above to test for validity, but you could implement some other method, if you wish.

If you're showing Form2 as a non modal window, then you should pass a reference of Form1 to Form2 first. This could be done in its constructor...

```
var form2 = new Form2(form1);
```

Or, you can pass it in the Show() method, to set form1 as its parent...

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show(form1);
```

Then, you can access the parent form via form2.Parent. However, you may have to cast it to a Form1 instance before you call your methods explicitly. And this can be done in the Closing event handler of Form2.

Further info here regarding modal and modeless windows:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx